# Giving images random name in PHP

Tags: php, random

this way i load image using php:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg("http://i.imgur.com/zWaQJNCb.jpg");
imagejpeg($image);
```

but problem is, if i want to save the image manually from my web browser to my desktop then all the images has same name like `ix.jpeg` [here file name is: ix.php] but i cant understand what is the way to configure the `header` so that images will have random name.. like `25xc.jpeg, 36s5a2f.jpeg...` while saving it on desktop.. any idea?

Comment: Why bother creating an image object?  Why not just `echo file_get_contents($some_file);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is will do the job!

```
$dt = date(time());
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'. $dt .'.jpg"');
$image=imagecreatefromjpeg("http://i.imgur.com/knNxDFnb.jpg");
imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my problem, you could have edited my post, since this is my solution.

Comment: yep! but u'r code will download the image... i put `Content-Disposition: inline;` so it will not download the image automatically ... got it... `:|`

Comment: The question was about generating dynamic names and not downloading automatically or not. (You can read the post name "Giving images random name in PHP") so forcing download is not a matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `filename` value in your `header` call.  [See Example 1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

```
<?php
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
?>
```

I'll leave the "generate a random string" part up to you.  I'd suggest basing it on the checksum of the file, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens if not hundred ways to do that.

1. Append `time()` after file name. This way all the file names will
   have a (unique)number.
2. Use a hashing function, like `md5()`.
3. Use this code-

   ```
   function generateRandomName(len) {
           $out = '';
           for($i=0; $i<len; $i++) {
               $out.=chr(rand(65,122));
           }
           return $out;
       }
   ```
4. Simply append `rand` function after your file name (But then the file names won't be of equal length).
5. Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need to do if you would like to generate unique names for your users, all you need to do is to use actual time stamp and use the filename parameter in the header, you can do like below (if you use random generation there will be a very few cases where you will get the same name twice) :

```
$dt = date(time());

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $dt .'.jpg"');
```

The above will generate unique images names like below :

> 1362504465.jpg

I hope this helps.

Comment: You can set my answer as the solution answer.

Comment: it will download the image, forcefully !

Answer (score 0):

This would make an 8 characters long name of letters a-z, but you could do some magic and/or use http://www.asciitable.com/

```
function randChar() {
    return char(rand(97, 122); 

    // Then you could either do a random number from 97 to 122 for a-z or just make an array of all the characters you would like in the filename. 
}

$filename = '';
$amountOfChars = 8;

for($i = 0; $i < $amountOfChars; $i++; ) $filename .= randChar();
```

Hope this helps